# How to use @Url.RouteUrl in submit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I had a div with the following:

```
@if (Model.Id == 0)
{
    <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("CustomerAddressEdit", new {Model.AddressId})">Change your address</a>
}
```

I want to remove link and replace it with button.
How to move this all stuff inside a submit button?

Comment: Just style the link using css to look like a button

Answer (score 0):

You can you the code like this:

```
@if (Model.Id == 0)
{
    <form action="@Url.RouteUrl(...)" method="get">
        <button type="submit">Change your address</button>
    </form>
}
```

Comment: thanks, and where to check @if (Model.Id == 0) ? before button?(input)

Answer (score -1):

```
@if (Model.Id == 0)
        {
            <input type="button" name="change" class="button " value="@T("Change")" 
                   onclick="setLocation('@Url.RouteUrl("CustomerAddressEdit", new {Model.AddressId})')" />
        }
```

here is it.